# Handler implementation file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the filename/url of the file where the jQuery handler function is implemented?

Let's say I have a massive codebase where there's no way of knowing in advance where my source code is. I have to find it. So, I use the following to get a click-event-handler function that is registered on the document:

```
$._data(document, "events").click[0].handler
```

It gives me all the registered events, but I can't tell where is that file. Actually I can do it, but in Chrome tools I have to go to Console, output the handler, right click and select "Show function definition". For 5 handlers that's not SO bad, but say for 50 it damn well is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. The ways you've listed are about it. Once you've got the code reference try and find a rarely used method and do a 'Find All' for it

Comment: But how does Chrome open the file then? There should be nothing magical about that. Or should it?

Comment: Chrome downloads all the files you've referenced and then interprets the JS within them. It doesn't need to know what specific file anything is in.